# Android Trackball on Custom Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, trackball

I have a custom dialog which extends the Dialog class and a simple custom layout like the one from below:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"
    >


<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:focusable="true"/>
```

My problem is that the trackball makes the text not visible when a row is selected like in the attached image.

[image]

The list_selector_background code is from Android and it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:state_window_focused="false" android:drawable="@color/transparent" />

<!-- Even though these two point to the same resource, have two states so the drawable will invalidate itself when coming out of pressed state. -->
<item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_disabled" />
<item android:state_focused="true"  android:state_enabled="false"                              android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_disabled" />
<item android:state_focused="true"                                android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition" />
<item android:state_focused="false"                               android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_transition" />
<item android:state_focused="true"                                                             android:drawable="@drawable/list_selector_background_focus" />
```

And my ListView xml code is this:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
          android:background="@color/white"
          android:cacheColorHint="@color/transparent">

</ListView>
```

I saw that on an AlertDialog (the one from Android) is working okay. What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Is the selected color, an image?

Comment: I haven't set any image for selection. I guess is the default color from Android...

Comment: android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"  what kind of image you have here?

Comment: I have edited my post. You can see there the code. End I tried to access the drawable from this selector but I can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this: remove "android" text from this line. like;

```
android:background="@drawable/list_selector_background"
```

add in list view

```
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
android:fadingEdge="none"
```

this one work for me

Comment: I have tried but it didn't work :(. I really don't know what the problem could be.

Comment: are you using listview in AlertDialog?

Comment: try this in java file: listView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
or in xml file in listview:
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"

Comment: Still not working. I have edited my post with the ListView code.

Comment: Thank you very much :D It's working now. I think that the problem was android:drawSelectorOnTop. Thanks again.